# Convert CURL request to Parse.com HttpWebRequest in cloud code

Tags: javascript, curl, parse-platform, httprequest

I need to run a cURL request in cloud code but I can't convert it successfully (return error code 401: unauthorized):

The cURL request format is:

```
curl --digest -u Key:Secret "http://example.com/" --form imagepath=@"animage.jpg" -X PUT
```

I'm trying this:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://example.com',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json",
   'Key': "xXXXXx",
   'Secret': "xXXXXXx",
  },
 body: {
  'imagepath': "http://.../photo.png"
 },
 success: function(httpResponse) {

  console.log(httpResponse.text);
 },
 error: function(httpResponse) {

  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
 }
});
```

[UPDATE]

I tried with GET method (to understand how it works) and this is working with that call (I've found the authorization line with google chrome developer inspector...):

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://example.com',

headers: {
Authorization: 'Digest username="XXxxXXXX", realm="API Name", nonce="XXXxxxXXX",     uri="example.com", response="XXXxxxXXX", opaque="XXxxxxXXX", qop=auth, nc=xxXXXxx,     cnonce="XXXxxxXX"'
},

success: function(httpResponse) {

console.log(httpResponse.text);
response.success("Okayyy!");
},
error: function(httpResponse) {

console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);

response.error("error");
}
});
```

But no way to make PUT method works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load a URL with basic auth. If that is true you can pass the credentials as part of the URL.

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://key:value@example.com',
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json",   
  },
 body: {
  'imagepath': "http://.../photo.png"
 },
 success: function(httpResponse) {

  console.log(httpResponse.text);
 },
 error: function(httpResponse) {

  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution but give me a 400 error code (bad request).

Comment: I noticed your curl command is using PUT but your code is using POST. I've changed the code, try this one.

Comment: Yes I have noticed this typo and tried with PUT without success :'( The response is: "Request failed with response code 400"

Comment: Strange just to make sure you did replace key:value with the actual values for them right?

Comment: Ha ha yes, don't worry I did change with my own key/value ;-) I think this is not caused by a bad auth because the error code isn't 400 (Unauthorized) but 401 (bad request). The API allows other request such as GET which works very well with your advice. The issue seems to come from the imagepath parameter.

Comment: Not really sure what your imagepath variable is about but in curl command you don't use full path, so try dropping the http://example.com part in your request see if that works.

Comment: But my image isn't in the same server than the example.com but it is in parse.com